# Spotify login error INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI android

Tags: android, redirect, authentication, callback, spotify

I am making an application which contain spotify integration, I was followed this link https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/

by the reference of this link I was put "festevo://callback" as callback redirect URI

when I was trying login into spotify every time I was getting same error.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
           android:host="callback"
           android:scheme="festevo" />
```

Please tell me why this happen...

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I see a couple of possible things that could've gone wrong:

- It's as simple as that you didn't save the redirect URI after you typed it in. (Double-check [My Applications](https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications/).)
- You didn't specify it properly in your application's manifest. (Double-check the manifest part in the [tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/))
- You didn't change the REDIRECT_URI value to festevo://callback as specified in the [tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/).

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Hello, i have another issue please help me to sort out if you know
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358212/spotify-in-eclipse-getting-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-spotify-sdk

Comment: the ui is a bit misleading. it's very easy to think you've saved your redirect uri by pressing add button, and since the page is a bit long, you might not see the warning and the save button. that happened to me. if someone from Spotify put a similar warning right under redirect uri section in that page when a change is made, that would avoid confusion imho.

Comment: Thanks keune, I'll make sure to bring it up.

Comment: Include a path after the first pair of forward slashes. For example: Your app name is My Awesome App The redirect URI may be my-awesome-app-login://callback or awesomeprotocol123://returnafterlogin.

For more information please refer this link Spotify Redirect URI Example