# Spotify in eclipse getting error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.spotify.sdk.android.playback.NativeSdkPlayer

Tags: android, eclipse, spotify, classnotfoundexception

getting this error at,

```
Player mPlayer = spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this,
new Player.InitializationObserver() {
      @Override
      public void onInitialized() {

      }
  });
}
```

I am working on eclipse and i was added classes.jar file getting from spotifysdk-1.0.0-beta6.aar into libs folder

Is there any other jar file missing for eclipse?

Thank you,

Comment: have you checked this jar from build path ?

Comment: yes, from build path->Order and export i was checked

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have done the same and have the same problem (Netbeans).

Comment: I move my project on android studio and its work fine, if you want to work with spotify player move your project on android studio