# Spotify Login with Meteor and xinranxiao:accounts-spotify

Tags: meteor, authentication, spotify, redirect, meteor-accounts

I am trying to add Spotify login features to my web app with **[accounts-spotify](https://atmospherejs.com/xinranxiao/accounts-spotify)** package. However I get redirect url errors.

```
<head>
  <title>testMeteorSpotify</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> loginButtons}}
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
```

Here are the packages i have:

```
meteor-base             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates    # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
session                 # Client-side reactive dictionary for your app
jquery                  # Helpful client-side library
tracker                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifiers      # JS/CSS minifiers run for production mode
es5-shim                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code

autopublish             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
accounts-ui
xinranxiao:accounts-spotify
```

I've created an application at with spotify's api portal and I entered the client secret and client id in the accounts-spotify setup login button.

[image]

[image]

After following with this procedure I still get a redierct error.
[image]

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:3000/_oauth/spotify?close` for the redirect URI.

Comment: is the redirect URI in the request URL?

Comment: Hey thank you for the replies . I switched the redirect URI to http://127.0.0.1:3000/_oauth/spotify?close with no success, but I think it's because my redirect url looks like the following. //accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d12a078de127492693230ee1b9a1380e&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/_oauth/spotify&state=eyJsb2dpblN0eWxlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QiLCJjcmVkZW50aWFsVG9rZW4iOiJjT2RZMG42MjBZcEhGTGNLZUtITHBrNV9CSlE5X3NoUXo1N3p6Rm5UWTM5IiwiaXNDb3Jkb3ZhIjpmYWxzZSwicmVkaXJlY3RVcmwiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDAvIn0=&scope=user-read-email

Comment: If I remove `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d12a078de127492693230ee1b9a1380e&redirect_uri=` from [redirecturl](https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=d12a078de127492693230ee1b9a1380e&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/_oauth/spotify&state=eyJsb2dpblN0eWxlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QiLCJjcmVkZW50aWFsVG9rZW4iOiJzcWZXZzNhczdoTjBkSGlPQWxzdlhaak1zWlRFS2ZiN1hRSFhCajhuaGhCIiwiaXNDb3Jkb3ZhIjpmYWxzZSwicmVkaXJlY3RVcmwiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjMwMDAvIn0=&scope=user-read-email) I do get a window that says I have logged in successfully.

Comment: Also, so everyone is aware. I did press 'save' after I submitted the redirect URI at spotify. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353227/spotify-login-error-invalid-client-invalid-redirect-uri-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We talked offline and the problem was that the service configurations were missing.

i.e. the following needs to exist:

```
(in server-side code)
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
  { "service": "spotify" },
  {
    $set: {
      "clientId": "<your clientId>",
      "secret": "<your secret>"
    }
  },
  { upsert: true }
);
```